# value not found in filter/map operation

Tags: scala, scala-collections

How can I modify the following code snippet so that the "attempts" variable is known in the handleFailure function?

```
def getLoginAttempts(username: String): Option[Long] = ...

getLoginAttempts(username) filter (attempts => attempts <= MAX_ATTEMPTS) map {
    handleFailure(username, attempts)
} orElse sendNotification()
```

compiler output => not found: value attempts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
getLoginAttempts(username) filter (attempts => attempts <= MAX_ATTEMPTS) map { attempts =>
    handleFailure(username, attempts)
} orElse sendNotification()
```

Or maybe I don't understand what is handleFailure?

Answer (score 2):

This would be more clearly expressed with pattern matching.

```
getLoginAttempts(username) match {
  case Some(attempts) if attempts <= MAX_ATTEMPTS => handleFailure(username, attempts)
  case _ => sendNotification()
}
```

This also makes it easy later on if you wish to distinguish the `None` case from the `Some(attempts), attempts > MAX_ATTEMPTS` case. IMHO, pattern matching is less obscure than `filter` and `map` on `Option` values, which simply perform the matching behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Howabout :

```
val attempts = getLoginAttempts(username).getOrElse(0)
if(attempts >= MAX_ATTEMPTS) handleFailure(username, attempts) else sendNotifications()
```